# My Masonry Images only show up in a single column

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, masonry

I am having trouble with the OMR one-month-rails tutorial. I am am making a pinteresting-like layout that moves photos upon windows resizing. I have followed the tutorial almost exactly.

However the photos are not filling out the page layout. The site is taking my photos and listing them as a single column: [Error](http://cl.ly/image/0t0z2d0c1C1p)

/app/assets/javascripts/photos.js.coffee :

```
$ ->
  $('#photos').imagesLoaded ->
    $('#photos').masonry
      itemSelector: '.bot'
      isFitWidth: true
```

index.html.erb:

```
<div id="photos" class="transitions-enabled">
  <% @photos.each do |photo| %>
    <div class="bot panel panel-default">
      <%= image_tag photo.image.url(:medium) %>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <%= photo.description %>
        <%= photo.user.email if photo.user %>
        <%= link_to 'Show', photo_path(photo) %>
        <% if photo.user == current_user %>
          <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_photo_path(photo) %>
          <%= link_to 'Destroy', photo, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

photos.css.scss:

```
#photos {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bot {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 214px;
}

.bot img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

How can I make this layout so that the photos are next to each other and not in a single column? I changed the "box" to "bot" because it conflicts with another css file I have. But even if I do change that css it doesn't matter because it still shows up as a single column.

EDIT:
I was able to sudo-fix this problem, via some css I found online.
New photos.css.scss file:

```
#photos {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bot {
 margin:5px;
 padding:5px;
 font-size: 11px;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 float: left;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #444;
 width: 214px;
}

.bot img {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
```

This has fixed my single-column issue. However, now there are large gaps in between my photo 'slides, like so: [Masonry Error](http://cl.ly/image/1D3U0w2W3R2U)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...
The OMR tutorial has the

> //= require tree .

line. I have excluded this line due to some errors from another piece of jquery. I hadn't manually inserted my

> //= require photos

line. I only included the

> //= require masonry/jquery.masonry

line. 
It works in production but is acted a little differently in development which is fine for me.